# How can I format headings and subheadings to this layout?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, typography

How can I format a book like the sample in the image? The chapter number uses the font Algerian, but I am not sure about the headings and subheadings. Are there similar latex fonts that I can incorporate easily? I use Texnic Center. 
[image: Sample Page]

Comment: With the `titlesec` package, for instance.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. I will try it out. So I will have to use the book class, right? I am having trouble identifying the fonts.

Comment: The report class also has chapters. For the font it will be tougher. In particular, for section titles, you need a font with a *condensed* version.

Comment: The closest I know should be `TeXGyre Termes` (but it doesn't have a condensed version).

Comment: How do I instruct latex to use it? :( I am too new to this. I have only worked with templates and stuff before.

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=27359&view=unread&sid=f048018b1b9e69a2e0fdb4a342ca07a2#unread)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution (I used `erewhon`, a clone and extension of Adobe Utopia).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{array, graphicx} \usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon} \usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\bfseries\Huge\lsstyle}%
{\titlerule[1.5pt]\vskip1ex\scalebox{1}[1.2]{\thechapter}\\[-1ex]\rule{5cm}{0.5pt}}{0ex}%
{#1\endgraf\titlerule\vskip2pt\titlerule[1.5pt]}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\bfseries\LARGE}{}{0em}{\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}\thesection & \MakeUppercase{#1}\\[-0.1ex]\hline\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{10}
\chapter{Green Technology and\\Green Business}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Green Business or Sustainable Business}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any chnce that you are also a member at LC? The question was [crossposted](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=27359&p=94397#p94397).

Comment: @Bernard. Thank you so much. There seems to be something wrong with my MikTex installation so I can't get it up an running. I will keep on trying.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, I am. I didnt know it wasn't permitted. I will take the query off LC just now.

Comment: @Bernard I get an error saying pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is possible only with scalable fonts.

Comment: I took out the option erewhon and also added \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} - and it works ok - except the normal paragraphs don't look so nice.

Comment: I didn't touch the normal paragraphs. What do you mean? They don't look so nice as before, or not so nice as you'd like?

Comment: Okay! It was a psychological thing, then, I guess. I felt that the normal font doesnt look as nice at it does in your example.

Comment: Do you mean Computer Modern or Latin Modern? It doesn't look like what you posted (and personally, I don't like them very much). There are many other fonts you can use. If you have no math, you actually can use any system font with xelatex.